# What is the etymology of the word крутить?

Tags: этимология

Is it connected to корчить and короткий?

Vasmer does not answer.

Comment: Wiktionary traces [крутить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#Этимология) and [короткий](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9#Этимология) to different roots, it seems that корчить could potentially be related to короткий through palatalization of the stem's T - короче - корчить, and to me they appear closer semantically

Answer (score 3):

*Крутить* is from the Proto-Slavic root *krǫt-, Old Church Slavonic *крѫтити*. In this word and in its cognates in other Indo-European languages, as Vasmer has it, we see the nasal element in the root. The Proto-Slavic nasal vowels developed from a combination vowel + nasal consonant when the Proto-Slavic law of the open syllables began to work and all the closed syllables got opened.

*Корчить* is from *корчи* 'spasms', which is from the Proto-Slavic **kr̩čь* < PIE *(s)ker 'to turn (крутить), to bend (гнуть)', related to the Latin *curvus* 'bent, curved' (изогнутый) and Greek *κυρτός* (kyrtós) with the same meaning. Here we see no nasal element in the root, so the etymological connection of *корчить* and *крутить* is dubious, although semantically they are prety close. On the other hand, *короткий* (from the same PIE root *(s)ker) is related to *корчить*, but surely not to *крутить*.

The original nasal consonant in the root of *крутить* makes it unrelated to the other two words.

Comment: I thought (s)ker- means cut (кора, скорлупа, short, scarce, скрести)

Comment: @Anixx - It looks like there were two hononymous IE roots _*(s)ker_, one with the meaning _cut_, and the other 'to turn': https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/(s)ker- So if they are really two different, unrelated roots, and not just two very different meanings of the same root, then _корчить_ and _короткий_ are unrelated, too.

Comment: also *ker- "horn/head"... but I am sure PIE had no homonymsous roots